# His head moves up and down. His head moves down and up

Tags: grammar

> 1. His head moves up and down.
> 2. His head moves down and up.

Do we have to use #1? What about #2? Can we use both?

Comment: If someone **dips** their head then it goes down and up.

Comment: You can use either one, but only #1 would sound idiomatic.

Comment: An alternative to #2 (US) could be, "He nodded once."

Answer (score 3):

"Up and down" is a **fixed phrase** meaning "in one direction and then in the opposite direction, especially repeatedly". The two opposite directions are often vertical, but not exclusively; I can walk up and down a level path. To reverse it when describing that kind of action would be non-standard and viewed as an error by most native speakers. If only two vertical motions altogether are being described, and the first is downwards, then we could say, for example: "he moved his head down and up again".

[Up and down](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/up-and-down)